# Azure Data Factory inactive pipelines/resources cost

Tags: azure-data-factory, linked-service, azure-mapping-data-flow, azure-cost-calculation

I want to know if there is a cost associated with pipelines, datasets, linked services, triggers and mapping data flows of Azure data factory when it is not in use.

if there is a cost associated with it, is there any way I can deprovision or disable the pipelines to avoid that cost as well.

Answer (score 0):

I understanding is the inactive pipelines were only charged in ADF v1 but they are no longer charged in ADF v2.

Please refer the doc for pricing details:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/

Comment: There is no cost involved for Inactive pipeline in ADF v2 unlike ADF v1.
n ADF v2, you only pay for data pipeline orchestration by activity run and activity execution by integration runtime hours (For IR charges are prorated by the minute and rounded up)

Email thread:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1015698/cost-factors-for-azure-data-factory.html